# SGML Parser in Plain C

Tags: c, parsing, sgml

I'm looking for an open-source SGML parser written in plain C. This is to parse bona-fide SGML, not malformed stuff.

Any ideas?

Comment: By pure curiosity, who does SGML (not XML) today?

Comment: The kind of companies using SGML are probably all using, and can afford, Omnimark for their SGML processing.

Comment: Financial instutitions (OFX) still uses SGML.

Comment: (OFX 1, that is; version 2 uses XML.)

Comment: Boeing's technical documentation - terabytes of stuff - is in SGML.  US DoD has been a heavy user, so you find SGML all over the military-industrial complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This came up on a fast Google search ([sgml c parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=sgml+c+parser)): http://www.w3.org/Library/src/SGML.html. Does that help?

Or perhaps this one: http://www.math.utah.edu/pub/sgml/sgmls/

Comment: I was hoping for someone with direct experience but I suppose SGML isn't exactly that common anymore :-)

Thanks, I think the first one sounds like the best bet.

Comment: The "SGML parser" at W3C isn't really one.  It was developed for the original WWW library (don't ask - long obsolete), and only handles a severely restricted subset of SGML syntax - basically, all that was thought to be "needed" for parsing HTML in the early days.

Comment: SGMLS is a true SGML parser developed by James Clark from something called the ARC-SGML Parsing Materials. He subsequently (1994) rewrote it from scratch in C++ as nsgmls (now an [open source project](http://openjade.sourceforge.net/doc/nsgmls.htm)) There are [other SGML parsers](http://xml.coverpages.org/publicSW.html) in C, such as YASP and YAO, but they're not easily found.

Answer (score 5):

There's OpenSP, which is part of the [OpenJade](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openjade/) project, but is implemented in C++. Might be close enough for your needs?

Comment: SGML is complicated stuff and there are few libraries. OpenSP is a good choice.

Comment: True. Writing a full SGML parser is not for mere mortals. There's plenty of goofy stuff in ISO 8879 (the SGML standard); it's a tribute to James Clark's skill that he got so much of it right in SP (now OpenSP).